# Azure DevOps Conditional execution of Job that depends on a Job in another Stage

Tags: azure-devops, conditional-statements, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

I have a `pipeline.yaml` that looks like this

```
pool:
  vmImage: image

stages:
  -stage: A
   jobs: 
     -job: a
      steps: 
     - script: |
          echo "This is stage build"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes"
        name: BuildStageRun
  -stage: B
   jobs:
      -job: b
       steps: #do something in steps

      -job: c
       dependsOn: a
       condition: eq(dependencies.build.outputs['BuildStageRun.doThing'], 'Yes')
       steps:
        - script: echo "I am scripting"
```

So, there are 2 stages, **A** with one job **a**, and **B** with 2 jobs **b** and **c**. I would like to have job **c** executed only when job **a** has executed. I tried to do so by setting the variable *doThing* in job **a** to Yes and then check this variable in job **c**.

But I get an error:

> Stage plan job **c** depends on unknown job **a**.

The varible definition and the definition of condition was taken from [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Do you have any suggestion on how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you can't depend on a job from another stage, you can depend stage B on stage A or job c on job b.

You can't achieve your goal with YAML conditions because you want to use a variable that you declared it in the first stage, the second stage doesn't know this variable, [Azure DevOps don't support it yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions):

> You cannot currently specify that a stage run based on the value of an
>   output variable set in a previous stage.

You can depend stage B on A, so if in stage A there is only one job you depend stage B on stage A:

```
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
```

Comment: Ok, this is what I suspected. I will need to modify the logic in the pipeline to achieve the same functionality then. I'm curious though. Do you have any explanation why this is not allowed?

Comment: Is it still accurate? I can't find such statement in linked doc.

Comment: @ravenwing - found a solution and posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68581906/9632623)

Answer (score 8):

While Shayki is correct that it is not supported - there is a workaround that I am currently using. That I used with the help of this blog https://medium.com/microsoftazure/how-to-pass-variables-in-azure-pipelines-yaml-tasks-5c81c5d31763

Basically you create your output as normal, and then publish the variables as pipeline artifacts. In the next stage, you read the artifact in the first job, and use that to construct your conditionals e.g.

```yaml
stages:

  - stage: firststage
    jobs:

      - job: setup_variables
        pool:
          vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
        steps:

          - powershell: |
              $ShouldBuildThing1 = $true
              # Write to normal output for other jobs in this stage
              Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildThing1;isOutput=true]$ShouldBuildThing1"
              # Write to file to publish later
              mkdir -p $(PipelineWorkspace)/variables
              Write-Output "$ShouldBuildThing1" > $PipelineWorkspace/variables/BuildThing1
            name: variablesStep

          # Publish the folder as pipeline artifact
          - publish: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/variables
            artifact: VariablesArtifact

       - job: build_something
         pool:
          vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
         dependsOn: setup_variables
         condition: eq(dependencies.setup_variables.outputs['variablesStep.BuildThing1'], 'true')
         variables:
           BuildThing1: $[dependencies.setup_variables.outputs['variablesStep.BuildThing1']]
         steps:
           - powershell: |
               Write-Host "Look at me I can Read $env:BuildThing1"

           - somethingElse:
               someInputArgs: $(BuildThing1)


  - stage: secondstage
    jobs:

      - job: read_variables
        pool:
          vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
        steps:
          # If you download all artifacts then foldername will be same as artifact name under $(Pipeline.Workspace). Artifacts are also auto downloaded on deployment jobs.
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              artifact: "VariablesArtifact"
              path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/VariablesArtifact

          - powershell: |
              $ShouldBuildThing1 = $(Get-Content $(Pipeline.Workspace)/VariablesArtifact/BuildThing1)
              Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildThing1;isOutput=true]$ShouldBuildThing1"
            name: variablesStep

      - job: secondjob
        pool:
          vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
        dependsOn: read_variables
        condition: eq(dependencies.read_variables.outputs['variablesStep.BuildThing1'], 'true')
        variables:
           BuildThing1: $[dependencies.setup_variables.outputs['variablesStep.BuildThing1']]
         steps:
           - powershell: |
               Write-Host "Look at me I can Read $env:BuildThing1"

           - somethingElse:
               someInputArgs: $(BuildThing1)
```

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a few options available from Microsoft now.

First is [job-to-job dependencies across stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-to-job-dependencies-across-stages)

From Microsoft:

> In this example, job B1 will run whether job A1 is successful or skipped. Job B2 will check the value of the output variable from job A1 to determine whether it should run.

```yaml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true"
     # or on Windows:
     # - script: echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true
       name: printvar

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    condition: in(stageDependencies.A.A1.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Job B1
  - job: B2
    condition: eq(stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['printvar.shouldrun'], 'true')
    steps:
     - script: echo hello from Job B2
```

Also, there's another option where you could [consume output variables across stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-to-stage-dependencies).

From Microsoft site:

> Stages can also use output variables from another stage. In this example, Stage B depends on a variable in Stage A.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true"
     # or on Windows:
     # - script: echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true
       name: printvar

- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.A.outputs['A1.printvar.shouldrun'], 'true'))
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Stage B
```